# Remap arrow keys in osx

Tags: macos, keyboard, remapping

I would like to remap my left, right, up & down keys to fn key + j, k, l, i in OSX.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found a way to do this: http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/

Answer (score 1):

[KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/document.html) apparently also works.

[image]